# Why does pandas not drop my duplicate values from the dataframe using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has some duplicate values. This is the code of how my dataframe is being created

```
# profit calculation
df['lowest_cumulative_price'] = df.Close.cummin()
df['highest_profit'] = df.Close - df['lowest_cumulative_price']
df = df.set_index(['Symbol']).groupby('lowest_cumulative_price')['highest_profit'].nlargest(3).reset_index()
print(df.head(20))
```

and this is how the dataframe looks like:

```
lowest_cumulative_price      Symbol  highest_profit
0                     90.90    SHREECEM        29374.50
1                     90.90    SHREECEM        29374.50
2                     90.90    SHREECEM        29003.55
3                     94.55         IOC            0.00
4                    128.00  HEROMOTOCO         2905.85
5                    128.00  HEROMOTOCO         2835.85
6                    128.00  HEROMOTOCO         2813.65
7                    128.10     DRREDDY         4390.10
8                    128.10     DRREDDY         4387.90
9                    128.10     DRREDDY         4277.90
10                   132.30   COALINDIA            0.00
11                   418.95   BRITANNIA         3206.10
12                   418.95   BRITANNIA         3197.05
13                   418.95   BRITANNIA         3118.80
14                   429.95        BPCL            0.00
15                   507.75  BHARTIARTL           14.75
16                   507.75  BHARTIARTL           13.75
17                   507.75  BHARTIARTL            9.55
18                   523.65  BHARTIARTL            0.00
19                   688.25  BAJAJFINSV         8980.35
```

After applying the `drop_duplicates` to my `df` it doesn't really remove the duplicate records:
here is how I am apply it:

```
# profit calculation
df['lowest_cumulative_price'] = df.Close.cummin()
df['highest_profit'] = df.Close - df['lowest_cumulative_price']
df = df.set_index(['Symbol']).groupby('lowest_cumulative_price')['highest_profit'].nlargest(3).reset_index()
top3_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['lowest_cumulative_price', 'Symbol', 'highest_profit'], keep='first')
print(top3_df.head(20))
```

```
lowest_cumulative_price      Symbol  highest_profit
0                     90.90    SHREECEM        29374.50
2                     90.90    SHREECEM        29003.55
3                     94.55         IOC            0.00
4                    128.00  HEROMOTOCO         2905.85
5                    128.00  HEROMOTOCO         2835.85
6                    128.00  HEROMOTOCO         2813.65
7                    128.10     DRREDDY         4390.10
8                    128.10     DRREDDY         4387.90
9                    128.10     DRREDDY         4277.90
10                   132.30   COALINDIA            0.00
11                   418.95   BRITANNIA         3206.10
12                   418.95   BRITANNIA         3197.05
13                   418.95   BRITANNIA         3118.80
14                   429.95        BPCL            0.00
15                   507.75  BHARTIARTL           14.75
16                   507.75  BHARTIARTL           13.75
17                   507.75  BHARTIARTL            9.55
18                   523.65  BHARTIARTL            0.00
19                   688.25  BAJAJFINSV         8980.35
20                   688.25  BAJAJFINSV         8814.10
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Just wondering if the value in `lowest_cumulative_price` is supposed to have the index number 0,2,3...20 appended to the actual value? Coz that might explain the duplicates.. Also it appears the duplicates were removed based on your subset. Notice the SHREECEM value with index 1. Others were preserved because not all columns in your subset matched.

Comment: I dont see duplicates in your data (with respect to the subset that you gave to the method)

Comment: @AnuragDabas No it doesn't work! because as you can see The symbol Names are being repeated.

Comment: `drop_duplicates()` method works as expected...so what is the problem?...I think that you need to pass 2 columns in `subset` parameter of `drop_duplicates()` method...so try this:`top3_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['lowest_cumulative_price', 'Symbol'], keep='first')`

Comment: @AniAggarwal Since ive reset_index() pandas is displaying indexes from 0,1,2,..20

Comment: Thanks I got it. Agreed with @AnuragDabas the subset operation was successfully executed and duplicates were removed.